# Data passing to a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
Fragment fragment = new Videonew_fragment();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

using above code for go to another fragment.i need to pass data along with this method.for data passing i used below code it not working perfectly.what i am doing wrong? help me?

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

Comment: You can access the Bundle in the fragment by using getArguments

Comment: String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");   .strtext always null in my new fragment

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the layout of your code, but you may be missing that you need to add the bundle to the specific fragment as you open it.

```
//First Create your arguments to pass
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");

//Create New Fragment    
Fragment fragment = new Videonew_fragment();
//Apply arguments
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
//Now create replace the fragment
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Thankyou for your feedback.i referred many stackoverflow questions but i could not get it.so finally used session for data passing.